# Как разбить массив на равные части?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как разбить массив правильно на равные части?
Есть массив `let arr = [1,2,3,4]`, есть число `let n = 2;`
Мне надо чтобы на выходе получилось `newArr = [ [1,2],[2,3],[3,4] ];`

У меня получилось вот так сделать, но по результату выводит не совсем то, что мне надо

```
let array = [1,2,3,4];
let n = 2;
let newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    
    newArr.push(array.slice(i, i + n));
        
}
console.log(newArr);
```

В конце появляется не нужный массив.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

остановите цикл на n раньше

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4];
let n = 2;
let newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length+1-n; i++) {
    
    newArr.push(array.slice(i, i + n));
        
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: спасибо, отлично. Объясните только зачем array.length мы прибавляем еще 1?

Comment: если поменять условие на i <= array.length-n; то не надо - у нас индекс массива не бывает равным length, а заканчивается на length-1.